# Pusher module is not found although installed

Tags: amazon-web-services, pusher, adonis.js

*Error received below:*

```
Error: Cannot find module 'Pusher'
Require stack:
- /home/ec2-user/realtime_map/node_modules/require-stack/src/index.js
- /home/ec2-user/realtime_map/node_modules/require-stack/index.js
- /home/ec2-user/realtime_map/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/src/Ioc/index.js
- /home/ec2-user/realtime_map/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/index.js
- /home/ec2-user/realtime_map/server.js

at /home/ec2-user/realtime_map/start/events.js(anonymous):3
1      //events.js
2
3      const Pusher = use('Pusher')
4      const Event = use('Event');
5      const Env = use('Env');
6
7      // set up Pusher
8      let pusher = new Pusher({

1 requireStack
  /home/ec2-user/realtime_map/node_modules/require-stack/src/index.js:44

2 Ioc._require
  /home/ec2-user/realtime_map/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/src/Ioc/index.js:345

3 Ioc.use
  /home/ec2-user/realtime_map/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/src/Ioc/index.js:742

Application crashed, make sure to kill all related running process, fix the issue and re-run the app
```

*Installed versions of pusher are;*

adonis-fullstack-app@4.1.0 /home/ec2-user/realtime_map
    └── pusher@3.0.0

adonis-fullstack-app@4.1.0 /home/ec2-user/realtime_map
    └── adonis-pusher@1.0.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error indicates that a module name `Pusher` could not be found, but your installation notes `pusher` being installed. 
Can you try lowercase p on your import:

```
const Pusher = use('pusher')
```

Comment: Fixed it, perfect